# Последовательное выполнение функций JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу самостоятельно осилить данную задачу. Прошу указать мне на ошибки.

Задача:
Есть форма, из которой необходимо извлечь загруженную информацию и передать в обработчик.

Вся сложность заключается в том, что необходимо загруженные изображения обработать на стороне клиента и только после этого передавать. Поскольку обработка файлов изображений требует времени, результат этих функций получаю позже, чем формирую массив для последующей передачи данных. Подскажите, как правильно это сделать?

```js
async function resizeBase64Img(base64, width, height) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  $("<img/>").attr("src", base64).on('load', function() {
    context.scale(width / this.width, height / this.height);
    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    deferred.resolve(canvas.toDataURL());
  });
  return deferred.promise();

}



async function F1() {

  let filesArr1 = document.getElementById('file1').files; // Забираем файлы из поля "Фото общего вида"
  ResizeImageArr = [];
  newPhotoB64Array = [];
  numCreated = 0; //Заводим счётчик для проверки выполнения цикла

  for (var i = 0; i < filesArr1.length; i++) {

    //filesArr1B64.push(getBase64(filesArr1[i])); // Переводим в base64 и наполняем массив


    function getBase64(file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
      });
    }

    let file = filesArr1[i];
    getBase64(file).then(
      data => (resizeBase64Img(data, 1200, 1200).then(function(newImg) {
        newPhotoB64Array.push(newImg);
      }))
    );

    numCreated++;
    if (numCreated === filesArr1.length) { //Если счётчик равен длинне массива - передаем готовый массив в функцию для вывода значения
      ResizeImageArr = newPhotoB64Array;
    }

  }


  //console.dir(ResizeImageArr0);                      
  return ResizeImageArr;
}

async function F2() {

  let filesArr2 = document.getElementById('file2').files; // Забираем файлы из поля "Фото общего вида"
  ResizeImageArr = [];
  numCreated = 0; //Заводим счётчик для проверки выполнения цикла

  for (var i = 0; i < filesArr2.length; i++) {

    //filesArr1B64.push(getBase64(filesArr1[i])); // Переводим в base64 и наполняем массив
    function getBase64(file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
      });
    }

    let file = filesArr2[i];
    getBase64(file).then(
      data => (resizeBase64Img(data, 1200, 1200).then(function(newImg) {
        newPhotoB64Array.push(newImg);
      }))
    );
    numCreated++;
    if (numCreated === filesArr2.length) { //Если счётчик равен длинне массива - передаем готовый массив в функцию для вывода значения
      ResizeImageArr = newPhotoB64Array;
    }
  }

  //console.dir(ResizeImageArr0);                      
  return ResizeImageArr;
}

async function F3() {

  let filesArr3 = document.getElementById('file3').files; // Забираем файлы из поля "Фото общего вида"
  ResizeImageArr = [];
  numCreated = 0; //Заводим счётчик для проверки выполнения цикла

  for (var i = 0; i < filesArr3.length; i++) {

    //filesArr1B64.push(getBase64(filesArr1[i])); // Переводим в base64 и наполняем массив
    function getBase64(file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
      });
    }

    let file = filesArr3[i];
    getBase64(file).then(
      data => (resizeBase64Img(data, 1200, 1200).then(function(newImg) {
        newPhotoB64Array.push(newImg);
      }))
    );
    numCreated++;
    if (numCreated === filesArr3.length) { //Если счётчик равен длинне массива - передаем готовый массив в функцию для вывода значения
      ResizeImageArr = newPhotoB64Array;
    }
  }

  //console.dir(ResizeImageArr0);                      
  return ResizeImageArr;
}

async function F4() {

  let filesArr4 = document.getElementById('file4').files; // Забираем файлы из поля "Фото общего вида"
  ResizeImageArr = [];
  numCreated = 0; //Заводим счётчик для проверки выполнения цикла

  for (var i = 0; i < filesArr4.length; i++) {

    //filesArr1B64.push(getBase64(filesArr1[i])); // Переводим в base64 и наполняем массив
    function getBase64(file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
      });
    }

    let file = filesArr4[i];
    getBase64(file).then(
      data => (resizeBase64Img(data, 1200, 1200).then(function(newImg) {
        newPhotoB64Array.push(newImg);
      }))
    );
    numCreated++;
    if (numCreated === filesArr4.length) { //Если счётчик равен длинне массива - передаем готовый массив в функцию для вывода значения
      ResizeImageArr = newPhotoB64Array;
    }
  }

  //console.dir(ResizeImageArr0);                      
  return ResizeImageArr;
}


  

async function drawShelves() {
  let res1 = await F1();
  console.log(res1);
  let res2 = await F2();
  console.log(res2);
  let res3 = await F3();
  console.log(res3);
  let res4 = await F4();
  console.log(res4);

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form id="mainForm">
  <input id="file1" type="file" name="file-0[]" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple>
  <input id="file2" type="file" name="file-0[]" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple>
  <input id="file3" type="file" name="file-0[]" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple>
  <input id="file4" type="file" name="file-0[]" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple>
  <button type="button" onclick="drawShelves();">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD**

Так будет работать, не хватало `await` перед `getBase64(file).then...`

```js
  async function resizeBase64Img(base64, width, height) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $("<img/>").attr("src", base64).on('load', function () {
      context.scale(width / this.width, height / this.height);
      context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      deferred.resolve(canvas.toDataURL());
    });
    return deferred.promise();

  }



  async function F1() {

    let filesArr1 = document.getElementById('file1').files; // Забираем файлы из поля "Фото общего вида"
    let ResizeImageArr = [];
    let newPhotoB64Array = [];
    let numCreated = 0; //Заводим счётчик для проверки выполнения цикла

    for (var i = 0; i < filesArr1.length; i++) {

      //filesArr1B64.push(getBase64(filesArr1[i])); // Переводим в base64 и наполняем массив


      function getBase64(file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
          reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
        });
      }

      let file = filesArr1[i];
      await getBase64(file).then(
        data => (resizeBase64Img(data, 1200, 1200).then(function (newImg) {
          newPhotoB64Array.push(newImg);
        }))
      );

      numCreated++;
      if (numCreated === filesArr1.length) { //Если счётчик равен длинне массива - передаем готовый массив в функцию для вывода значения
        ResizeImageArr = newPhotoB64Array;
      }

    }


    //console.dir(ResizeImageArr0);
    return ResizeImageArr;
  }

  async function F2() {

    let filesArr2 = document.getElementById('file2').files; // Забираем файлы из поля "Фото общего вида"
    let ResizeImageArr = [];
    let newPhotoB64Array = [];
    let numCreated = 0; //Заводим счётчик для проверки выполнения цикла

    for (var i = 0; i < filesArr2.length; i++) {

      //filesArr1B64.push(getBase64(filesArr1[i])); // Переводим в base64 и наполняем массив
      function getBase64(file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
          reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
        });
      }

      let file = filesArr2[i];
      await getBase64(file).then(
        data => (resizeBase64Img(data, 1200, 1200).then(function (newImg) {
          newPhotoB64Array.push(newImg);
        }))
      );
      numCreated++;
      if (numCreated === filesArr2.length) { //Если счётчик равен длинне массива - передаем готовый массив в функцию для вывода значения
        ResizeImageArr = newPhotoB64Array;
      }
    }

    //console.dir(ResizeImageArr0);
    return ResizeImageArr;
  }

  async function F3() {

    let filesArr3 = document.getElementById('file3').files; // Забираем файлы из поля "Фото общего вида"
    let ResizeImageArr = [];
    let newPhotoB64Array = [];
    let numCreated = 0; //Заводим счётчик для проверки выполнения цикла

    for (var i = 0; i < filesArr3.length; i++) {

      //filesArr1B64.push(getBase64(filesArr1[i])); // Переводим в base64 и наполняем массив
      function getBase64(file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
          reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
        });
      }

      let file = filesArr3[i];
      await getBase64(file).then(
        data => (resizeBase64Img(data, 1200, 1200).then(function (newImg) {
          newPhotoB64Array.push(newImg);
        }))
      );
      numCreated++;
      if (numCreated === filesArr3.length) { //Если счётчик равен длинне массива - передаем готовый массив в функцию для вывода значения
        ResizeImageArr = newPhotoB64Array;
      }
    }

    //console.dir(ResizeImageArr0);
    return ResizeImageArr;
  }

  async function F4() {

    let filesArr4 = document.getElementById('file4').files; // Забираем файлы из поля "Фото общего вида"
    let ResizeImageArr = [];
    let newPhotoB64Array = [];
    let numCreated = 0; //Заводим счётчик для проверки выполнения цикла

    for (var i = 0; i < filesArr4.length; i++) {

      //filesArr1B64.push(getBase64(filesArr1[i])); // Переводим в base64 и наполняем массив
      function getBase64(file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
          reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
        });
      }

      let file = filesArr4[i];
      await getBase64(file).then(
        data => (resizeBase64Img(data, 1200, 1200).then(function (newImg) {
          newPhotoB64Array.push(newImg);
        }))
      );
      numCreated++;
      if (numCreated === filesArr4.length) { //Если счётчик равен длинне массива - передаем готовый массив в функцию для вывода значения
        ResizeImageArr = newPhotoB64Array;
      }
    }

    //console.dir(ResizeImageArr0);
    return ResizeImageArr;
  }




  function drawShelves() {
    Promise.all([
      F1(),
      F2(),
      F3(),
      F4(),
    ]).then(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result);
      }
    );

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="mainForm">
  <input id="file1" type="file" name="file-0" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple>
  <input id="file2" type="file" name="file-0" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple>
  <input id="file3" type="file" name="file-0" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple>
  <input id="file4" type="file" name="file-0" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple>
  <button type="button" onclick="drawShelves();">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, что откликнулись! Второй вариант отлично срабатывает. Но есть проблема, в каждом результате выполнения функция выводятся все файлы. https://prnt.sc/tM3uWAOPuce0 (Уточнение: эта ошибка встречается и в моем варианте. Так что я уже с этой проблемой пришёл)

Comment: @ВикторУспенский поправил ответ